# Написание бота на Android

Tags: эмулятор, android, c++, бот, qt

Здравствуйте. Задался задачей - написать бота для игры на Андроид. Хочу попробовать реализовать на эмуляторе простой кликкер в определённых местах. Вот незадача, я не нашёл никаких руководств и подсказок, кроме официального эмулятора Андроида. Я планировал реализовать это на Qt: вроде там есть эмулятор и средства. От бота требуется лишь нажатия на экран в определенной точке и сдвиг точки вправо/влево. У кого есть поэтому поводу информация?

Comment: я думаю это нереально

Comment: Почему нет? Чем отличается кликер на винде от кликера на эмуляторе андроида в винде? Кликер просто посылает через WinApi команду нажатия с определёнными координатами (X,Y). Меня интересуют средства запуска и получения управления к андроиду.

Comment: наверно потокобезопасность, хотя существуют средства для автоматического тестирования интерфейсов, на их основе может что то и получится

Comment: Есть идея управлять окном эмулятора и в нём уже провоцировать нажатия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чем вызвано желание писать именно на Qt? Если единственный фактор - это знание Qt, то имхо лучше посмотреть в сторону Java - инфы однозначно больше, если не знакомы с Java, это не критично, после Qt переход будет мягким. Полезные ресурсы:

- [подборка уроков на русском, освещена тема одиночного и множественного касания](http://startandroid.ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html);
- [много полезных примеров как на java,  так и на с](http://idev.by/category/android/).

Comment: Спасибо, начал ознакамливаться!